# Youtube iframe only shows code instead of a window

Tags: php, mysql, iframe, youtube

I'm working on a simple blogengine and i found a huge bug. The use can create a siple blogpost and use a javascript that creates a short iframe code. Here is an example:

```
<iframe width="640" height="510" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/OMvFPp8dncU"
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

It send the whole text (post text and youtubecode) to a mysql server, the field it's inserted to is a varchar(255).
But when it's suposed to display the video, it shows the code. I have searched and read the code plenty of times to findout whats wrong but i can't find it.

Here is the "display code" that shows the posts:

```
<?php 
include_once('scripts/MySQL.php');

$sqlCommand = "SELECT id, title, text, date, publisher FROM news WHERE published='1' ORDER BY id 
ASC"; 
$query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error()); 

$menuDisplay = '';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
$title = $row["title"];
$text = $row["text"];
$date = $row["date"];
$publisher = $row["publisher"];

$news .= '<table width="760" align="center">
<tr>
<td align="left"><h1>' . $title . '</h1></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left">
<p>
' . $text . '
</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><h6><b>Published: ' . $date . ' by ' . $publisher . '</b></h6><br /><hr></td>
</tr>
</table>';

} 
mysqli_free_result($query); 
?>
```

Can some one help me find whats wrong and explain why it shows the code instead of the video, please c:

Here is links to screenshots:
[screenshot 1](http://fridh.tk/blogg.jpg)

[Screenshot 2](http://fridh.tk/ddd.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: I have posted two links to screenshots now. You can find them at the bottom of the text i posted.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a problem that was created by inserting the data into the mysql database. You can try a htmlspecialchars_decode where you set $text to get back the original html code:

```
$text = htmlspecialchars_decode($row["text"]);
```

Comment: If this answer solve your problem ... why not upvote and mark it as a solution? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.

Change:

```
' . $text . '
```

To

```
echo $text;
```

For some reason it makes a difference.